# Why won't Lightroom let me merge more than two photos for a panoroma?

Tags: lightroom, panorama

I have watched several videos to create a panorama and Lightroom will only let me use two photos. Is there a way to change settings or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you selecting the member images to stitch? Have you tried stacking?

Comment: Do the images have enough overlap?

Comment: It works with 10 for me easily. What message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

How are you attempting to select the individual images?

1. In the Library module, select grid view.
2. Hold down the CTRL key as you click on each image to select them all.
3. Right Click on one of the selected images, find Photomerge in the menu, and click on Panorama.

There must be a reasonable level of overlap between individual images (I usually allow between 1/4 to 1/3 of the image width as overlapping), and the focal length should be the same for all the individual images (Don't change the zoom when you're taking them)
Sometimes the Photomerge module won't allow you to create a panorama with one or more of the panorama options it presents.
If it says it can't create a panorama in for example Perspective mode, try one of the others and it may work.

Answer (score 0):

The limit in Lightroom for panorama photo merge is a maximum long dimension of 65,000 pixels or a maximum pixel count of 512 megapixels.

It's not a configuration choice, and it's not based on the number of source images (outside of the resulting pixel count).

You would select the images you want, and then choose the merge option.  If you choose 10 images, it should merge those (if it can).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old question, I just had the same issue, and found out why:

LightRoom is extremely memory hungry when merging. **You need to have *at least* 10 GB free memory on your machine, plus some for each photo**. If there is not enough memory, you get a not-helpful message ("LightRoom couldn't merge..." or "Error merging photos").
I just merged 8 photos (raw, 18 MPixel each), and needed 12.5 GB of total memory, on an otherwise naked Windows 10 system [I run LR in a virtual machine, so it is easy to adjust total memory, and it started working after I gave it 13 GB].
Merging 14 photos needed 13.8 GB; merging 4 needed 9 GB.